# How can I intercept keyboard events with Perl?

Tags: perl, winapi

Is there any way on Perl to identify if a keyboard event is triggered on Win32 before the key itself reach its GUI application ?

Answer (score 2):

As with any other language, you can use the [Windows API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::API) to install [a hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I doubt it will be worth the effort. Why not try [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Just researched [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-gui-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05248.html), and I think this is what you need.

It's an example script that uses RegisterHotkey (in the same way that AutoHotKey does) to have your script catch a keypress, even when it doesn't have focus. For my needs, it's much better to have my Perl script do this instead of relying on a separate program to forward the keypress.

Comment: Could you avoid using bit.ly links? Thanks